# Is there a way that I can set the width of two buttons appearing at the bottom of a page to 75?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code that displays two buttons at the bottom of my screen:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10" IsVisible="{Binding TwoBtnsVisible}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="#999999" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource pointButton2}" Text="Don't Know" Command="{Binding NButtonClickedCommand}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" BorderColor="#999999" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource pointButton2}" Text="Easy" Command="{Binding YButtonClickedCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

The width of the buttons fills the screen with a small amount to spare on either side and in between.

I would like to set the width of the buttons but it seems to not be possible. Is there some way I could do this so that each button is still spaced out nicely but has a width of just 75?

Comment: You wanna set an absolute amount width to your Buttons? It contradicts with Grid's Width="*"  which says fill all screen.

Comment: Do you wanna distribute those two buttons equally and both having 75 width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid size will be based upon its parent container (that you did not include), so assuming you do not want to alter it, you can use `ColumnSpan`. With 6 Proportional(`*`) columns, and a button width of two columns, that works out to:

> 100% width / 6 columns * 2 buttons of 2 column width = 66% of total width and thus 16.5% padding on the sides of the buttons

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Red" BorderColor="#999999" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Text="Don't Know"  />
    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="Red" BorderColor="#999999" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Text="Easy" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this two properties to each button.
It *should display them as you describe.

```
WidthRequest="75"
HorizontalOptions="Center"
```